# facing issue in creating pivot from data fetched form the db

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

i am making an excel  project where  user will select the date and will fill server / database name from which data will populate in the sheet that is already there in excel workbook with proper columns name. now there will be two sheets created (filled with the sql data) and pivot of each sheet i want to create. here is the 1st macro for prod named sheet

```
Sub Prod()
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UserInput").Activate ' a sheet where date picker and db/server names are taken from user
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim slctqry As String
Dim dealdate As String
Dim today As String
Dim msg As String
msg = "Sorry, for this date data is yet to come"
today = Range("B2").Value  'B2 cell has today() function
today = Format(today, "yyyy-mm-dd")
dealdate = Range("B1").Value 'date picker is linked to this cell
dealdate = Format(dealdate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=sql123abce\sql01;Initial Catalog=sqldb;User ID=abcd;Password=Windows;Integrated Security=SSPI"
con.Open
If (dealdate > today) Then
MsgBox msg
ElseIf (dealdate = today) Then
slctqry = "select Number,Premium, TransactionID, money from traders(nolock)"
slctqry = slctqry & " where convert(date,tradedate,103)='" & dealdate & "'"
Set rs.ActiveConnection = con
rs.Open slctqry
ActiveWorkbok.Sheets("Prod").Activate ' prod named worksheet where data will be copied from SQL db
Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset (rs)
ElseIf (dealdate < today) Then
slctqry = "select Number,Premium, TransactionID, money from tradersaudit(nolock)"
slctqry = slctqry & " where convert(date,tradedate,103)='" & dealdate & "'"
Set rs.ActiveConnection = con
rs.Open slctqry
'Dim ws4 As Worksheet
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Prod").Activate
Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset (rs)
End If
con.Close
End Sub
```

for db/server taken from user and data will filled in Test named sheet, the macro used is

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset


Function GetConnectionString() As String

   Dim strCn As String
    strCn = "Provider=sqloledb;"
    strCn = strCn & "Data Source=" & Range("Server") & ";"
    strCn = strCn & "Initial Catalog=" & Range("Database") & ";"
    If (Range("UserID") <> "") Then
        strCn = strCn & "User ID=" & Range("UserID") & ";"
        strCn = strCn & "password=" & Range("Pass")
    Else
        strCn = strCn & "Integrated Security = SSPI"
    End If

    GetConnectionString = strCn

End Function

Sub Test()

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UserInput").Activate
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Sql As String
Dim dealdate As String
Dim today As String
Dim msg As String
msg = "Sorry, for this date data is yet to come"
today = Range("B2").Value
today = Format(today, "yyyy-mm-dd")
dealdate = Range("B1").Value
dealdate = Format(dealdate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
' open connection
cn.ConnectionTimeout = 100
cn.Open GetConnectionString()
If (dealdate > today) Then
MsgBox msg
ElseIf (dealdate = today) Then
Sql = "select Number,Premium, TransactionID, money from traders(nolock)"
Sql = Sql & " where convert(date,tradedate,103)='" & dealdate & "'"
Set rs.ActiveConnection = con
rs.Open Sql
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Activate ' test sheet is there alerady with proper column  names
Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
ElseIf (dealdate < today) Then
Sql = "select Number,Premium, TransactionID, money from traders(nolock)"
Sql = Sql & " where convert(date,tradedate,103)='" & dealdate & "'"
Set rs.ActiveConnection = cn
rs.Open Sql
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Activate
Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
End If
cn.Close
End Sub
```

Now data has been populated in sheets Prod and Test successfully. next macros come for Pivot creation.

```
 Dim bReport As Workbook, Report As Worksheet, pivotSheet As Worksheet 'To set up my workbook & worksheet variables.

    Set bReport = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    Set Report = bReport.Worksheets.Add 'Create the worksheet to place the SQL data
    Set pivotSheet = bReport.Worksheets.Add 'Create the worksheet to place the Pivot Table

    Dim pivotSource As Range 'To set up the variable representing your pivot data.
    Set pivotSource = Report.UsedRange 'You can define a specific range, but this assumes the data is the only thing on the Report sheet.

    Dim tableName As String
    tableName = "Pivot_Prod"  'name of pivot report i wanted to create from data in sheet Prod

    bReport.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
            SourceData:=pivotSource).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=pivotSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
                tableName:=tableName

    Set pt = pivotSheet.PivotTables(tableName)
    pivotSheet.PivotTableWizard TableDestination:=pivotSheet.Cells(1, 1)
    Set pOne= pt.PivotFields("Number")
    Set pTwo = pt.PivotFields("Premium")
    Set pthree = pt.PivotFields("TransactoinID")
    Set pFour = pt.PivotFields("money")

    pOne.Orientation = xlRowField 'This assigns the orientation of a given field to xlRowField.
    pTwo.Orientation = xlRowField
    pTwo.Subtotals(1) = False 'This denotes there will be no subtotal for this field.
    pThree.Orientation = xlRowField
    pThree.Subtotals(1) = False
    pFour.Orientation = xlDataField
    pFour.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
```

The same for test sheet as well.

@lopsided- In your code file you are creating new sheet to get data from sql db. but where and how should i link my prod and test sheets to cache to make them as pivot source? I mean in your approach if i call macro prod() or Test() to get data in worksheet named report that we are adding here. then how could we go ahead in that case? 
in above code i'm getting error in pivotcache.add code line. It seems a minor change is reuired, please see if you can make the correction.

Comment: same as for your previous question .... have you declared and set Sheet1 properly? I don't see it in your code

Comment: yes mike Set Sheet1 = New Excel.Worksheet i added but it gave error too. and PT cache i didn't get from google how to use here in this code. i'll be more than happy if you can help in declaring this and adding pivotcache as well. because the data i fetched from db is already there in the sheet but why its not creating pivot from that data,i din't get.

Comment: @honey I've never used the "New" operator in VBA. Mine would always be Set Book1 = Excel.ActiveWorkbook. Then Set Sheet1 = Book1.Worksheets.Add

Comment: thanks Lopsided. but again invalid use of the property eror is coming in  "Set Sheet1 = Book1.Worksheets.Add"

Comment: @honey No worries, I'm working on a lengthy answer for you right now. It will be ready shortly.

Comment: @honey Also, lose the Select statements. They are pointless here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TBH, pivot tables in VBA are a real pain. A while back I decided to use them for a few projects and have avoided them ever since. The correct method for implementing a pivot cache for your code is as follows:

```
'First, define the range that includes your source data. This would be the data you pulled from SQL, and presumably inserted into a different sheet using CopyFromRecordset. 
'NOTE: If you have not copied the data from the recordset onto a worksheet, visit the links in this post to find out how.
'Also note, I always define the workbooks and worksheets I will be using in a project, and then reference them via their variables. This makes my code less error prone, I find.

Dim bReport As Workbook, Report As Worksheet, pivotSheet As Worksheet 'To set up my workbook & worksheet variables.

Set bReport = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set Report = bReport.Worksheets.Add 'Create the worksheet to place the SQL data
Set pivotSheet = bReport.Worksheets.Add 'Create the worksheet to place the Pivot Table

'******************************************************************************************************************
'Here you will insert your SQL data into the Report worksheet to be used as the source of the Pivot Table data.
'   ....Your code here....
'******************************************************************************************************************

Dim pivotSource As Range 'To set up the variable representing your pivot data.
Set pivotSource = Report.UsedRange 'You can define a specific range, but this assumes the data is the only thing on the Report sheet.

'Next you will decide on the name of the Pivot Table
Dim tableName As String
tableName = "Poll Table"

'Now here is what you've been waiting for...the ever-elusive PivotCaches method.
bReport.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=pivotSource).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=pivotSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
            tableName:=tableName

Set pt = pivotSheet.PivotTables(tableName) 'Set a Pivot Table variable to our new Pivot Table    
pivotSheet.PivotTableWizard TableDestination:=pivotSheet.Cells(1, 1) 'Place the Pivot Table to Start from A1 on the new sheet
```

Your field definitions look correct so this should get you past your PivotCaches issue, which will undoubtedly bring you to the next Pivot Tables issue.

For additional assistance, see the following links:

- [Using CopyFromRecordset to paste data into Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.copyfromrecordset%28v=office.11%29.aspx)
- [Excel Pivot Tables: Sort Fields, Values & Dates, use Custom Lists,
  with VBA](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=148%3aexcel-pivot-tables-sort-fields-values-a-dates-use-custom-lists-with-vba&catid=79&Itemid=475)

---

Also, here is a fully working example of using a Pivot Table from a project I did to format and filter credit card receipts:

```
Sub amexTable()

Dim i As Integer, k As Integer, j As Integer
Dim Report As Worksheet, reportBook As Workbook, pivotSheet As Worksheet
Dim Row As Range, Col As Range, pivotSrc As Range, pivotDest As Range

Set Report = Excel.ActiveSheet
Set reportBook = Report.Parent
Set pivotSheet = reportBook.Worksheets.Add
pivotSheet.Name = "Amex Pivot Table"

'************************************
'Declare variables for pivot headers
'************************************
Dim pDate As PivotField, pDesc As PivotField, _
pCardmember As PivotField, pAccount As PivotField, pAmount As PivotField
Dim pGL As PivotField
Dim Table_Name As String
Dim pt As PivotTable

'*******************************
'Declare and create pivot table
'*******************************
Table_Name = "Amex Pivot Table"
Set pivotSrc = Report.Range("A7:F" & Report.UsedRange.Rows.Count)

reportBook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=pivotSrc).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=pivotSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
            TableName:=Table_Name

    Set pt = pivotSheet.PivotTables(Table_Name) 'Set a Pivot Table variable to our new Pivot Table


    pivotSheet.PivotTableWizard TableDestination:=pivotSheet.Cells(1, 1) 'Place the Pivot Table to Start from A1 on the new sheet

    Set pCardmember = pt.PivotFields("Cardmember")
    Set pAccount = pt.PivotFields("Account #")
    Set pDate = pt.PivotFields("Date")
    Set pDesc = pt.PivotFields("Description")
    Set pAmount = pt.PivotFields("Amount")



    pCardmember.Orientation = xlRowField 'This assigns the orientation of a given field to xlRowField.
    pDate.Orientation = xlRowField
    pDate.Subtotals(1) = False 'This denotes there will be no subtotal for this field.
    pDesc.Orientation = xlRowField
    pDesc.Subtotals(1) = False
    pAccount.Orientation = xlRowField
    pAmount.Orientation = xlDataField
    pAmount.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
    pt.SortUsingCustomLists = True 'Sets the pivot table to use a custom sorting list as described in the link below:

    '   Excel Pivot Tables: Sort Fields, Values & Dates, use Custom Lists, with VBA
    '   http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=148:excel-pivot-tables-sort-fields-values-a-dates-use-custom-lists-with-vba&catid=79&Itemid=475

    pivotSheet.Columns.AutoFit
    pivotSheet.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    pivotSheet.Range("A1:E1").Merge
    pivotSheet.Cells(1, 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    pivotSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "AMEX Pivot Table" 'Header'

    Application.Run myColor(pivotSheet.Cells(1, 1), "blueHeader") 'My custom function to format the header.

    Application.Run Alternate_Row_Colors(3, pivotSheet) 'My custom function to format alternating row colors.

End Sub
```

One final note...For debugging purposes, this code should be place within a module and not ThisWorkbook.

---

**UPDATE**

@Honey: In response to...

> @lopsided- In your code file you are creating new sheet to get data
>   from sql db. but where and how should i link my prod and test sheets
>   to cache to make them as pivot source?

My pivot table source references the used range in my **Report** worksheet variable. In the code I gave you, my SQL data was in a new worksheet which we assigned to this **Report** worksheet variable. In your code, your SQL data is in an existing worksheet named "UserInput", which you neglect to assign to a variable (bad habit). **All you need to do to make my code work with yours is change the value of the Report variable.**

In other words, change this:

```
Set Report = bReport.Worksheets.Add 'Create the worksheet to place the SQL data
```

To this:

```
Set Report = bReport.Worksheets("UserInput") 'Assign your data worksheet to the Report worksheet variable.
```

Comment: thank you so much Lopsided for a clearcut solution. bReport.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=pivotSource).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=pivotSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
            tableName:=tableName        this line is still giving previous error 1004. it would be great if you share you emailid i'll give you my whole code. because i'm not sure where i'm going wrong in this code.

Comment: @honey I don't normally post my email, however if you edit your question to include your new code, then we maybe could find the solution. I did test my code before posting it so I don't think the error is there. With any luck, your issue may just be a case of misspelled variables or an incorrect select statement.

Comment: no. i have shared my complete code on http://pastebin.com/BxdgFqre . the only issue is where to link report(in your solution) to the worksheet that i have filled with sql data. it would be grat if you just take a look at this pastebin.com link. may be you better understand the complete project. and yes please don't mind for asking your emialID. i didn't know abt pastebin.com earlier.

Comment: @honey I've updated my answer to reflect the new code you posted.

Comment: @Lopsideed- thank you so much. as i'm new to this so asked for each step repeatedly. but now on i would make it more readable like assigning sheet to the variable. Well thanks again for you kind support.

Comment: @honey You're right that; that is how I will describe it from now on. Feel free to up-vote my answer to show your appreciation :D have a good day